# cocoapods spec lint error when i uploaded an framework to it

Tags: objective-c

A couple of weeks ago, I uploaded an framework to cocoapods。And now i want to update the framework ,but have some problems :
 StreamKit (1.1.6)
    - ERROR | [iOS] xcodebuild: Returned an unsuccessful exit code. You can use `--verbose` for more information.
    - NOTE  | xcodebuild:  Headers/Public/StreamKit/StreamKit.h:14:9: fatal error: 'NSObject+StreamKit.h' file not found.
 here is the spec [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMx46.png)

so ,please help me ,thanks